# Integration of $\sqrt{ x^2 - x\cdot \sin(x) + 4}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate

$$\sqrt{ x^2 - x\cdot \sin(x) + 4}$$

with respect to $dx$?

I tried solving this using substitution,  but it doesn't seem to work.  Can somebody give me a little direction on how to  proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Even using special functions, the antiderivative does not seem to be possible.

For the integral, series expansion around $x=0$ could be a possible solution since 
$$\sqrt{ x^2 - x\, \sin(x) + 4}=2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{480}-\frac{31 x^8}{80640}+\frac{31
   x^{10}}{725760}+\frac{2213 x^{12}}{319334400}+O\left(x^{14}\right)$$ Trying for
$$I_a=\int_0^a\sqrt{ x^2 - x\, \sin(x) + 4}\,dx$$ we would get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.1 & 0.20000 & 0.20000 \\
 0.2 & 0.40000 & 0.40000 \\
 0.3 & 0.60002 & 0.60002 \\
 0.4 & 0.80009 & 0.80009 \\
 0.5 & 1.00026 & 1.00026 \\
 0.6 & 1.20064 & 1.20064 \\
 0.7 & 1.40137 & 1.40137 \\
 0.8 & 1.60266 & 1.60266 \\
 0.9 & 1.80476 & 1.80476 \\
 1.0 & 2.00800 & 2.00800 \\
 1.1 & 2.21275 & 2.21275 \\
 1.2 & 2.41948 & 2.41948 \\
 1.3 & 2.62871 & 2.62870 \\
 1.4 & 2.84100 & 2.84098 \\
 1.5 & 3.05699 & 3.05695 \\
 1.6 & 3.27738 & 3.27727 \\
 1.7 & 3.50290 & 3.50264 \\
 1.8 & 3.73438 & 3.73377 \\
 1.9 & 3.97272 & 3.97137 \\
 2.0 & 4.21902 & 4.21616
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

The above approximation is not too bad for "small" values of $a$. We can make if better if we consider
$$J_{k,a}=\int_{2k \pi}^{2k\pi+a}\sqrt{ x^2 - x\, \sin(x) + 4}\,dx$$ Chanking variable $x=2k \pi+y$
$$J_{k,a}=\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{4 \pi ^2 k^2+4 \pi  k y-(2 \pi  k+y) \sin (y)+y^2+4}\,dy$$ and using the Taylor expansion of $\sin(y)$, the integrand becomes
$$2 \sqrt{\pi ^2 k^2+1}\left(1+\frac{\pi  k y}{4 (\pi ^2 k^2+1)}-\frac{\left(\pi ^2 k^2\right) y^2}{32 \left(\pi
   ^2 k^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{\pi  k \left(16 \pi ^4 k^4+35 \pi ^2 k^2+16\right)
   y^3}{384 \left(\pi ^2 k^2+1\right)^3}+\frac{\left(64 \pi ^6 k^6+241 \pi ^4
   k^4+320 \pi ^2 k^2+128\right) y^4}{6144 \left(\pi ^2
   k^2+1\right)^4}\right)+O\left(y^5\right)$$ for acceptable results as show below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & a &\text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.25 & 1.66333 & 1.66333 \\
 1 & 0.50 & 3.35705 & 3.35704 \\
 1 & 0.75 & 5.08364 & 5.08350 \\
 1 & 1.00 & 6.84782 & 6.84701 \\
 1 & 1.25 & 8.65666 & 8.65350 \\
 1 & 1.50 & 10.5197 & 10.5102 \\
 1 & 1.75 & 12.4494 & 12.4250 \\
 1 & 2.00 & 14.4607 & 14.4060 \\
& \\
 2 & 0.25 & 3.19659 & 3.19659 \\
 2 & 0.50 & 6.42490  & 6.42489 \\
 2 & 0.75 & 9.68763 & 9.68749 \\
 2 & 1.00 & 12.9896 & 12.9888 \\
 2 & 1.25 & 16.3377 & 16.3348 \\
 2 & 1.50 & 19.7412 & 19.7326 \\
 2 & 1.75 & 23.2117 & 23.1901 \\
 2 & 2.00 & 26.7631 & 26.7151 \\
& \\
 3 & 0.25 & 4.75443 & 4.75443 \\
 3 & 0.50 & 9.54087 & 9.54086 \\
 3 & 0.75 & 14.3621 & 14.3620 \\
 3 & 1.00 & 19.2230 & 19.2223 \\
 3 & 1.25 & 24.1304 & 24.1277 \\
 3 & 1.50 & 29.0935 & 29.0853 \\
 3 & 1.75 & 34.1236 & 34.1029 \\
 3 & 2.00 & 39.2341 & 39.1883
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to have an elementary antiderivative.  Maple didn't find one; Wolfram Alpha timed out.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this substitution below. From the point I stopped on, it should be a matter of organizing things and doing basic stuff.

$$\eqalign{
  & \int {\sqrt {{x^2} - x\sin x + 4} } dx = \int {\sqrt {4\left( {{{{x^2}} \over 4} - {{x\sin x} \over 4} + 1} \right)} } dx = 2\int {\left( {{{{x^2}} \over 4} - {{x\sin x} \over 4} + 1} \right)} dx  \cr 
  & x = 2\tan \theta   \cr 
  & {{dx} \over {d\theta }} = 2{\sec ^2}\theta   \cr 
  & 2\int {\left( {{{4{{\tan }^2}\theta } \over 4} - {{4ta{n^2}\theta } \over {4\sqrt {4 + 4{{\tan }^2}\theta } }} + 1} \right)} 2{\sec ^2}\theta d\theta   \cr 
  & 2\int {\left( {{{\tan }^2}\theta  - {{ta{n^2}\theta } \over {2\sec \theta }} + 1} \right)} 2{\sec ^2}\theta d\theta  \cr} $$

(sorry if I left anything wrong in the middle of all that!)

Comment: Wrong.  If $x = 2 \tan(\theta)$, $\sin(x) = \sin(2 \tan(\theta))$.  I don't see anything like that in your last two formulas.

Comment: You left out the square root .it should be $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x\sin(x)}4+1}$